# return multi variable to all blade files

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to duplicate variables in the pages of a site to be defined in one place.
I did a little search and I got this code

```
class BaseController extends Controller {


    public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter(function() {
            View::share('setting',Settings::find(1));
        });
    }
    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

i added this code to baseController and work it.

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter(function() {
            View::share('setting',Settings::find(1));
        });
    }
```

But here's just a variable defined, I need to define other values.
help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer
put this variables in array and use it.

```
View::share('datamaster',['setting' => $setting=Settings::find(1),
             'nav'=>$nav,
             'catpro_address' => $catpro_address,
             'apple_pro_cat'=> $apple_pro_cat,
             'sound_pro_cat'=>$sound_pro_cat,
             'watch_pro_cat'=>$watch_pro_cat,
             'storage_pro_cat'=>$storage_pro_cat,
             'other_pro_cat'=>$other_pro_cat,
             'mobile_pro_cat'=>$mobile_pro_cat,
             'tablet_pro_cat'=>$tablet_pro_cat]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter(function() {
            View::share('setting',Settings::find(1));
            //you can add more
            View::share('variable_name', $variable_value); 
        });
    }
```